# Foolproof primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

I just happened to hear about a prime number test which works 100% of the cases in an university lesson about cryptography.

It should be something like:

> if $p$ divides every coefficient of $(x-1)^p - (x^p -1)$ then $p$ is a prime

My question is: why can't we use it? does it take too long to test? 
I would really appreciate some help on this subject, even just with a link for a paper about it, since I don't recall the name and I couldn't find useful stuffs on web yet. Thank you :)

Comment: This takes $p$ divisibility tests, even leaving out the calculation of the coefficients.  Just checking directly if $p$ is divisible by any number from $2$ to $\sqrt{p}$ is faster.  (I.e., yes, it takes too long to test.)

Comment: Just to make a point, the very **definition** of prime number is necessarily a "prime number test which never fails". The existence of such a thing is not surprising.

Comment: Thanks to point out my bad english, but what I meant is that there are tests (e.g. Fermat little thm) which can fail for some numbers

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that testing Fermat is faster, but this is 100% true :)

Comment: This is well-known, e,g, it is often used to motivate expositions of the AKS primality test, e.g. see the [Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#concepts) We don't use the simple form of the test because it is inefficient (exponential time).

Comment: @FrancescoBruzzesi as mjqxxx says, this approach is not rejected because it takes a long time, but because it takes **much longer** than other 100% true alternatives, like trial division by primes up to $\sqrt p$. Even with numbers small enough that such basic tests are feasible, this method is infeasibly slow. To demonstrate this to yourself, I suggest you try it out on $839899$ and $839989$, one of which is prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This test, in combination with the words "fool proof" indicate that it almost certainly came from the numberphile video about the AKS test.  The method you show is presented, called the AKS test (which it isn't), is claimed to be very fast (which it isn't), and then implies that we had no other way of figuring this out before -- that this was a revolution in practical use (which it isn't).  Later in the video he mentions offhand that, well, there's a little fiddly other stuff that makes it a little faster.  Which is to say, all of AKS.

I believe this method was first pointed out in ~1670 by Leibniz, according to a few sources (e.g. "Primality Testing and Integer Factorization in Public-Key Cryptography" by Yan, page 130).  It's exponential time and *much* less efficient than just doing trial division to $\sqrt n$.  It is stated on page 2 of the AKS paper as Lemma 2.1, which they immediately point out takes too much time.  The rest of the paper finds clever ways to reduce the work done.

Wikipedia: [AKS primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)

[Primes is in P](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf)    - the paper by Agrawal, Kayal, and Saxena.

"Why can't we use it?"  We can, just like we can use [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) or trial division.  They work.  They're just not computationally practical once the numbers get large (remembering that "large" is very subjective -- whatever you think of as a "large number" is someone else's "small number").

"Does it take too long to test?"  Yes.  We have **much** faster methods.

A brief further aside.  Let's say you do everything mentioned in the paper.  You have the real AKS.  This is a *theoretical* breakthrough.  A very simple method that shows what people long believed but had eluded proof: primality testing is deterministic polynomial time without any conjectures.  We had deterministic polynomial time assuming the ERH.  We had randomized polynomial time with no conjectures.  We had deterministic almost-but-not-quite polynomial time with no conjectures.  AKS lets us now say during discussions, "...and since primality testing is deterministic polynomial time, the whole algorithm is therefore ..."

The gotcha is that computationally even the proper AKS is still much slower than methods we were already using.  APR-CL and ECPP are the typical methods used in practice.  They are "fool proof" if you want to use that term.  They are many orders of magnitude faster.  There is also probable prime testing, such as BPSW or random-base Miller-Rabin, which is much faster yet, albeit with small chances of being wrong (both have deterministic methods for 64-bit inputs, so are "fool proof" for that size).